# White Page of Death on submit

Tags: validation, codeigniter, php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Reference - What does this error mean in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12769982/reference-what-does-this-error-mean-in-php)

I am having an issue with the following section of code:

I can get the error notices in the validation but the next step = valid code I just get a white page,  Any Ideas?

I have checked the error settings and I have set it in the public_html php.ini file and I still don't get errors

```
function create_sale()
{       
$this->template->append_metadata( js('debounce.js', 'sales') );        
$this->template->append_metadata( js('new_sale.js', 'sales') );        

    // -------------------------------------
    // Validation & Setup
    // -------------------------------------

    $this->load->library('form_validation');

    $this->sale_rules[1]['rules'] .= '|callback__check_slug[insert]';

    $this->form_validation->set_rules( $this->sale_rules );

    foreach($this->sale_rules as $key => $rule)
    {
        $sale->{$rule['field']} = $this->input->post($rule['field'], TRUE);
    }

    // -------------------------------------
    // Process Data
    // -------------------------------------

    if ($this->form_validation->run())
    {
        if( ! $this->sales_m->insert_new_sale( $sale, $this->user->id ) ):
        {
            $this->session->set_flashdata('notice', lang('sales.new_sale_error'));  
        }
        else:
        {

            $this->session->set_flashdata('success', lang('sales.new_sale_success'));   
        }
        endif;

        redirect('admin/sales');
    }

    $this->template->set('sale', $sale)
                   ->build('admin/new');

}
```

Comment: What framework are you using? Also, write a title that makes sense.

Comment: @gAMBOOKa It seems he's using CodeIgniter.

Comment: `Any Ideas?` One - see your error log.

Comment: When your form validates, the user is redirected: `redirect('admin/sales');`. Is that page blank?

Comment: @dev-null-dweller its not showing in logs and I have run phpMate in text mate and thats fine

Comment: @Joseph Silber No because I get the errors,  just not the success

Comment: please don't use the [`if (xyz):`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) form, it's something that just shouldn't be in PHP.

Comment: @τεκ It even has sad faces in the syntax; it's that bad!

Comment: I see what you did there ;-P Also, no disrespect to your coding style, it's just generally deprecated :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You said that your code is valid but you get a white page.

Most of the time when you get a white page you will simply have an error in your code.

As is the case here:

You suddenly have an `endif;` in your code which you don't want there.

Enable error reporting please:

Include this code in your bootstrap file:

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
```

Remember to disable this in production!

To remove the error change:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    if( ! $this->sales_m->insert_new_sale( $sale, $this->user->id ) ):
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('notice', lang('sales.new_sale_error'));  
    }
    else:
    {

        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', lang('sales.new_sale_success'));   
    }
    endif;

    redirect('admin/sales');
}
```

to:

```
if ($this->form_validation->run())
{
    if( ! $this->sales_m->insert_new_sale( $sale, $this->user->id ) )
    {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('notice', lang('sales.new_sale_error'));  
    } else {
        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', lang('sales.new_sale_success'));   
    }

    redirect('admin/sales');
}
```

Comment: @PeeHaha,  I have done your code and still a whitepage.  In my config I have $config['sess_cookie_name']  = 'pyrocms' . (ENVIRONMENT !== 'dev' ? '_' . ENVIRONMENT : ''); in my index.php dev =  error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);

Comment: @Jess McKenzihi: If you still get a white page you should really check whether `admin/sales` page is outputting anything. What do you get when you go to that URL manually?

Comment: I get the sales admin page it loads fine.

Comment: @Jess McKenzie: can you `print('something')` just before the redirect. And also do a `print('something else'); exit();` at the top of the admin/sales page and tell me the result.

Comment: I have done the print before the redirect still white and the top of the sales worked - I did them sep as I need to access the sales page to add a sale

Comment: @Jess McKenzie: that's strange. However I might see a problem with your script. Add an `exit();` after the redirect. Or the script will continue to execute. So do this: `redirect('admin/sales'); exit();`

Comment: Nope still white,  wish I could get a **word** error!

Comment: @JessMcKenzie let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2871/discussion-between-peehaa-and-jess-mckenzie)

Answer (score 2):

You have too many closing curly braces, remove the 'endif' in your script and it should work.

Comment: you may want to change the ERROR_REPORTING and related options in the php.ini so you can see this more easily

Comment: Good catch, either use curly braces or if: else: endif;... preferably curly braces

Comment: @Ashley that just killed the page before submit

Answer (score 1):

CodeIgniter is notorious for the "white screen of death".

Generally when I've run into it, it's been because of the way they set up their database error handling (it's not good).  Database errors aren't handled when `$db['default']['db_debug']` is set to FALSE.  Any query or connection attempt that fails just returns false. Execution continues after a bad query, which can result in a white screen of death.  If you're lucky, you'll get an error message in the logs in some cases, but in most you won't, as the `query()` function just silently returns false without logging anything.

If you set it to TRUE, then you can be in an even worse position, because any database error will automatically result in CodeIgniter calling it's own `show_error()` function and generating a 500 HTTP response, and you have no chance of handling it on your own.

This is the most common way to get the WSOD that I'm aware of.  I haven't used the 2.0 versions of CI, but it was the case in the 1.7 versions.  You may want to try setting `db_debug` to true in your database.php config file until you find out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @zombat but it is set to true

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your `redirect()` is failing to redirect (instead just leaving a blank page sans redirect) for some reason or another. Toss a debug message before it to check.

Comment: @tek  I have done this (still white) it also uses the same redirect for the error so it must be working